# How to find the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ in order to find ideals of norm $20$ (not prime).

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Very new to algebraic number theory, so I was just wondering if someone could clarify how to do this?

Essentially I would like to proceed by finding elements of norm 20. So $20=2^2\times5$ so I guess I would want to figure out what ideals have norm $2$ and $5$?

Comment: There is no prime ideal with norm $20$ since the norm of a prime is always a power of a prime number.

Comment: But there would be ideals with norm 20 - presumably by finding all prime ideals with norm 2 and 5.

Comment: Ah so you want to find prime ideals with norm $2$ and $5$ then?

Comment: If that works - yes. (Would that help me find ideals of norm 20?)

Comment: You should probably edit your question then, since right now it suggests that you are only interested in finding prime ideals.

Comment: @AnInvisibleCarrot yes that works, ideal norm is multiplicative, so to find ideals of norm 20 we can find ideals of norm all prime powers dividing 20 and take suitable products. So you need to find all prime ideals of norm 2,4 and 5. Even though 4 is not prime it is possible for a number field in general to have prime ideals of norm 4 but none of norm 2! So you need to either find prime ideals of all these norms, or show none exist. The fundamental tool is normally the Kummer-Dedekind theorem see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf .

Comment: Would I also have to find prime ideals of norm 10?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in finding ideals with a prescribed norm, you should use that the norm is multiplicative, hence if you want to find $I\subset \mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ with $N(I)=20$, it suffices to find primes $\mathfrak q_1,\mathfrak q_2$ with norm $2$ (or with norm $4$ if there is no prime of norm $2$) and $5$ and then set $I=\mathfrak q_1^2\mathfrak q_2$ (resp. $\mathfrak q_1\mathfrak q_2$ in the second case).

Now quite generally, let $p$ be a prime number and suppose you are interested in identifying the primes $\mathfrak q$ living over $p$ (i.e. contracting to $(p)$ along the inclusion $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$). For this a very convenient tool is the following result due to Kummer and Dedekind:

> Let $K$ be a number field and let $p$ be a prime number. Suppose that $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[a]$ for some $a\in\mathcal O_K$. Let $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$. Let $\bar f=\prod_i \bar g_i^{e_i}$ be the prime decomposition in $\mathbb F_p[X]$ and lift the $\bar g_i$ to monic polynomials $g_i$ in $\mathbb Z[T]$. Then $p\mathcal O_K=\prod_i (p,g_i(a))^{e_i}$ is the factorization of $p\mathcal O_K$ into prime ideals in $\mathcal O_K$.

You can find this result for example as Theorem 3.41 in Milne's [notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf).

Applying this to the situation you are interested in, you will find $a=\sqrt 2$ and hence $f=X^2-2$. Modulo $2$ this gives you $\bar f=\bar X^2$, hence the ideal $(2,\sqrt 2)=(\sqrt 2)$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ and is the unique prime ideal lying over $2$. Modulo $5$, on the other hand, you find that $\bar f=\bar X^2-2$ is irreducible since it has no roots in $\mathbb F_5$, hence the unique prime ideal lying over $5$ is $(5)$.

Now the only thing left to do is to compute the norm of these ideals. For this you need to know the degrees of the residue field extensions. But since $2$ ramifies in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ you already know that $N(\sqrt 2)=2$. Now $5$ does not ramify but also has a unique prime ideal in its fiber, hence the degree of residue field extensions must be $2$ and we find $N(5)=5^2=25$. Hence you have shown that in fact no ideal of norm $20$ can exist in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.

Comment: I have not been taught this theorem that you have mentioned - are there other elementary ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given a quadratic field $K$ with ring of integers $A$, the (unique) decomposition of a rational prime $p$ into a product of prime ideals in $A$ is classically known. For reasons of degrees of ramification and inertia, there are 3 and only 3 possible cases : 1) $p$ is inert, i.e. $p$ remains prime, i.e. $pA$ is a prime ideal $P$ ; 2) $p$ is ramified, i.e. $pA$ is of the form $P^2$ ; 3) $p$ splits, i.e. $pA=P.P'$, the product of 2 distinct conjugate prime ideals. The characterization of these 3 cases can be conveniently expressed in terms of quadratic residue symbols, see e.g. D. Marcus, "Number Fields", chap.3, thm. 25.

In your case, where $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $A=\mathbf Z[\sqrt 2]$ is a PID, the mentioned theorem tells you that an *odd* prime $p$ is a norm iff $p$ splits, iff $(\frac 2 p)=+1$. The "complementary formula" for Legendre symbols reads $(\frac 2 p)= (-1)^{(p^2 -1)/8}$, so you can check e.g. that $3,5,11...$ are not norms, whereas $7,23,31...$ are. Explanation : Let $H=$ {$\bar1,\bar3,\bar5,\bar7$} be the group of invertible elements of $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$. The map $H \to (\pm 1)$ defined by $\bar p \to (\frac 2 p)$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $H'=$ {$\bar1,\bar7$}.